# How to pass a List<string> from Form to user controls in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form with 4 UserControls, each for a different page.
Some of my controls are used on multiple UC.

What I'm trying to do is this :

Form

```
public List<string> MyList;
MyList = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\"));
```

and I'm trying to access the list in my UserControl :

uc1

```
foreach (string item in MyList)
{ 
    ComboBox.Items.add(item); 
}
```

And obviously, MyList in the UserControl isn't recognized.
Be it uc1 or any other one.

I don't understand what the problem is.
Also it's obvious from the problem I think but, I'm a beginner so, please avoid complicated answers, I'll afraid of programming after that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make property in your `UserControl`, something like

```
public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
```

in your Form, when needed, pass reference to `UserControl`:

```
public List<string> MyList;
MyList = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\"));
uc1.MyList = MyList;
```

Comment: Sadly, the `uc1.MyList` gives me an error : _An object reference is required for the non-static field, or property 'uc1.MyList'_   EDIT : Simply added static to the UC declaration and it works. So thanks :)

Comment: @PeterQuill `uc1` should be the name of your user control that exists on `Form`

Comment: It is. I just added 'static' in the declaration `public static List<string> MyList { get; set; }`